# Drink Different / Drink Differently?

Tags: grammar

There's this online beer company in Germany that is offering Belgian and other foreign beers and they are on Sky here all the time with their commercials.

Now, they are called Beer Deluxe and their tagline is: "Beer Deluxe! Drink different!" Just wondering if 'Drink Different' is grammatically correct? Should it not be 'Drink Differently!'? What is the correct grammatical explanation here?

Comment: There is no grammatical explanation. It's just marketing speak, which is mimicking Apple's ["think different"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Think_different).

Comment: Addressed at [As quick as we can?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/137855/as-quick-as-we-can)

Comment: @Matt Эллен There is; there's a resurgence of flat adverbs.

Answer (score 1):

This is not grammatically correct, but is most likely an allusion to the Apple "Think Different" campaign, which is perhaps one of the most famous advertising campaigns in modern history. See:

[Think Different](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Think_different)

Also it is worth saying that in English there is a tendency in some circumstances to use adjectives for adverbs. I have noticed it more frequently in the American dialect. For example, here we have "real good coffee" rather than "really good coffee". Compare for example "that is a fast car" to "that car is fast."

However, let there be no doubt that "drink different" is not correct, the verb requires an adverb not an adjective and "different" is always an adjective. However, it is a deliberate rhetorical device to make you stop and think, probably thinking of that campaign.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be technically correct, but in spoken AmE there are a lot of colloquial nuances.

In the US, we would understand "Drink different".  "Drink differently," would conjure images of someone with a straw up their nose.

In the same way, if you overheard someone say "You look different," to somebody, you could assume that they had lost weight, or had a different hairdo. "You look differently," would mean there was something odd about their vision or opinions.

Comment: But "look" is a special type of verb (I don't know the technical term), equivalent to "seem" or "appear to be", which can take a predicate adjective. So "you look different" is standard usage, and not similar to "drink".  Agreed, the ad is not asking us to drink differently, but rather to drink [something] different.