# Adverbs - do they still exist?

Tags: adverbs, flat-adverbs

Why do people say "I want it done fast"?

Fast is modifying 'done' which is the past tense of a verb.
Verbs are modified by adverbs - which end with 'ly'.
They should say "I want it done quickly".

A similar mistake arises about cars (and other the things).
It may be a fast car, but you drive it quickly - you do not drive it fast.

I discussed this with a professor of computing who said "It doesn't matter - it's common usage".
Common or not, it is wrong.
Yes, or no?

Does anyone care anymore?
Does anyone know anymore?

Comment: Not all adverbs end in *-ly*; *fast* is an adverb. See [dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fast). If somebody says *"I want it done quick"* (which they do), you might have reason to complain.

Comment: This question has an answer [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/137855/as-quick-as-we-can). Adverbs like _quick_ are "flat adverbs" and they have a long history of usage.

Comment: _**Fast** is another flat adverb with no normal (-ly) equivalent: “Run fast.”_ http://www.dailywritingtips.com/flat-adverbs-are-flat-out-useful/

Comment: Where do your flat adverbs leave the other example - - - "It may be a fast car, but you drive it quickly - you do not drive it fast"?

Comment: No, you drive quickly. The car is fast.

Comment: OK, it appears common usage trumps correctness.  Bye

Comment: @MarkTucker In a sense, correctness is defined by popularity of a certain usage. :)

Comment: The point is that "fast" doesn't have a related adverb ending in _ly_; (there's no *fastly"). So it can belong to both the adjective and adverb categories depending on its function in the clause: " He owned a fast car" (adjective) and "He drove fast" (adverb).

Comment: There are a number of adverbs that don't use the -ly suffix: **very**, **quite**, **together**, **well**...

Comment: [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/fast) says *fast* **is** an adverb.

Comment: @MarkTucker Common usage and correctness aren't mutually exclusive... Don't come to EL&U asking for affirmation of your own opinions. Come to EL&U to ask for meaningful answers (that may prove you wrong; oops you might learn something). Meaningful answers have been given for this question and they're well-documented and justified.

Comment: On another note, I think one of the best examples of a flat adverb (offered in NVZ's answer) is _hard_. Pushing the door hard and hardly pushing the door are two very different things.

Comment: @MarkTucker It is common in more informal contexts to drop the '-ly'. "He drives quick" is OK informally, but shouldn't appear in an edited newspaper or school work.

Answer (score 5):

***Fast*** is an adjective, and an adverb as well. — [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/fast)

> *adjective* 1. Moving or capable of moving at high speed
> *"a fast and powerful car"*
>
> *adverb* 1. At high speed
> *"he was driving too fast"*

Adverbs that don't use the normal *-ly* suffix are called **flat adverbs**. — [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_adverb)

> A flat adverb is an adverb that assumes the form of a related adjective, most often when words ending in *-ly* are used without the *-ly*. Though once quite common, flat adverbs have been largely phased out by their *-ly* counterparts. This shift owes to 18th-century grammarians who insisted that adverbs end in *-ly*. Nonetheless, flat adverbs are preferred in some idioms, as in "take it easy" and "sleep tight".

[Mark Nichol of Daily Writing Tips](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/flat-adverbs-are-flat-out-useful/) lists some flat adverbs: *bright, clean, close, deep, far, fast, flat, hard, kind, quick, right, sharp, slow, soon, and tough*.