# What adjectives can be used as adverbs?

Tags: parts-of-speech, is-it-a-rule, predicate, flat-adverbs, zero-derivation

Are the following sentences acceptable to native speakers?

1. I want it so **bad**.
2. The children grew up **happy and healthy**.
3. Jimmy works **hard**.
4. He followed her **quick**.

What adjectives can be used as adverbs? Are there rules for that?

Comment: Hello, wada. You have to be careful; in your example (2), 'happy and healthy' actually **are** adjectives in what is called a resultative (it could, interestingly, alternatively here be a depictive) construction (they refer to the children as they are growing up and/or when they have grown up). // If you look up 'hard', you will see that there is also an adverb usage (an 'intercategorial polyseme'!). // The other two examples are non-standard / colloquial to unusual forms using adjectives where traditional English requires adverbs (badly; quickly).In fact, ...

Comment: ['Quick'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/137855/as-quick-as-we-can) is considered allowable as an adverb, but this has been covered here before. [Mark Nichol](https://www.dailywritingtips.com/flat-adverbs-are-flat-out-useful/) has written a good article entitled ['flat adverbs'](https://www.dailywritingtips.com/flat-adverbs-are-flat-out-useful/).

Comment: All fine for me, but in 2) I'd say *happy and healthy* really are adjectives, and in 3) there is no alternative adverbial form. 1) and 4) are less formal than the -ly versions - this doesn't really stand out in 1) because it feels informal anyway, but it does in 4), which is neutral. I wouldn't say any if the examples involve using adjectives as adverbs - it's just that adverbs sometimes have the same form as adjectives. Past participles sometimes have the same form as the simple past, but we don't say we are using the simple past as a past participle.

Comment: @minty "In 3) there is no alternative adverbial form." *Jimmy works* ***strenuously***? ;) But, yes, there is no adverbial form of *hard* that actually means *hard* (which *hardly* does not).

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. There are alternative adverbs, for sure - there almost always are - but there is no alternative adverbial form of the lexeme *hard*. My point was that this makes it unlike *quick* and *bad*, both of which have two adverbial forms - the flat adverb and the -ly adverb.

Comment: Wada, why do you think none of those are not already adverbs? Is it merely because they don''t all  end in *-ly* via derivation from an adjective as many adverbs of manner are formed? Have you looked these words up in dictionaries to see whether they are never adverbs? What exactly did you find there? Please edit your question with this information.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Might I please prevail upon you to move your contributions to the answer box?

Comment: @Minty Please move your contribution to the answer box.

Comment: @tchrist I almost never close-vote and give an 'answer'. These questions are not new here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I hadn't noticed the close vote was yours, sorry! But the user has not returned, so we don't really know what it is that they're asking here. It seems overly broad, and somewhat misguided. And no research from dictionaries, let alone from [Wipikedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_adverb). Probably we can find a dup to close it against under the `prescriptivist-poppycock` tag.

Answer (score 0):

In comments Minty wrote:

> All fine for me, but in 2) I'd say *happy and healthy* really are adjectives, and in 3) there is no alternative adverbial form. 1) and 4) are less formal than the -ly versions - this doesn't really stand out in 1) because it feels informal anyway, but it does in 4), which is neutral. I wouldn't say any if the examples involve using adjectives as adverbs - it's just that adverbs sometimes have the same form as adjectives. Past participles sometimes have the same form as the simple past, but we don't say we are using the simple past as a past participle.

and

> There are alternative adverbs, for sure - there almost always are - but there is no alternative adverbial form of the lexeme *hard*. My point was that this makes it unlike *quick* and *bad*, both of which have two adverbial forms - the flat adverb and the -ly adverb.

Answer (score 0):

In comments Edwin Ashforth wrote:

> Hello, wada. You have to be careful; in your example (2), 'happy and healthy' actually **are** adjectives in what is called a resultative (it could, interestingly, alternatively here be a depictive) construction (they refer to the children as they are growing up and/or when they have grown up). // If you look up 'hard', you will see that there is also an adverb usage (an 'intercategorial polyseme'!). // The other two examples are non-standard / colloquial to unusual forms using adjectives where traditional English requires adverbs (badly; quickly). In fact, ...
>
> ['Quick'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/137855/as-quick-as-we-can) is considered allowable as an adverb, but this has been covered here before. [Mark Nichol](https://www.dailywritingtips.com/flat-adverbs-are-flat-out-useful/) has written a good article entitled ['flat adverbs'](https://www.dailywritingtips.com/flat-adverbs-are-flat-out-useful/).

Comment: I recommend [the Wikipedia article on flat adverbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_adverb).